# approve a payment in PayPal via php

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I write a PHP script with cURL that should approve a payment in PayPal.
It work like this:
I got this link from website:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?VERSION=3.2&cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7ND07251WN147471E&useraction=commit
the token is a temporary uniq id of payment.
on this page I insert credit card/PayPal account.
then, I redirect again to the website of the seller for final confirm.
I need to write a script that will approve payment by his token.
the script will take the token from given link, and will approve the payment.
I searched a lot in google for solution and I find some PayPal API's.
When I started to dig the API's I find out that those API's are only for sellers.
Those API's let the seller integrate PayPal checkout to their website, but there isn't any function that can help me do what I want.
Anybody know about any solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you format this normally? It looks like a poem.

Comment: You said: "When I started to dig the API's I find out that those API's are only for sellers"
You need to have a Business or Premier account to use Express Checkout like you're currently trying to. Those accounts can use API calls. Only Personal accounts can't.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal offers some SDK's here http://paypal.github.io/ 
You would want the Merchant SDK. There is a PHP one in there you can use to help build your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call. I don't know if anyone would provide you with a custom cURL script to submit the payment - I would be interested in seeing it if one is provided.

Answer (score 0):

DoExpressCheckoutPayment is also function for the seller. after the buyer pay, he redirected back to the site of the seller, and then the php code in the site execute the DoExpressCheckoutPayment  function. I look for the function that will approve the payment instead of the buyer(me).